# multiple ping test with parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, ping

I have a number of child servers which are pingable from the parent server. The parent server is accessible from another automation server.

The requirement is to execute ping test parallelly across around 100 child servers from the parent server with a script running on the automation server.

The parent server is part of a NETAPP cluster so does not allow running any script / custom command on its terminal, so the logic needs to be controlled from the automation server itself.

I have tried using xargs something like below

cat child.csv | xargs -P4 -I {} bash -c "ssh parent 'ping -c4 {}'"

where child.csv - contains the child server IPs.

While this works well, but it creates 4 ssh connections to the parent which is not desirable.

I have written another script which has a single ssh connection but this executes sequentially not parallelly, which is also not desirable. This is depicted below.

```
cat tryssh.sh
#!/bin/bash

 ssh -tt xxx@parent << POC
 ping -c4 child1
 ping -c4 child2
 exit
POC
```

The requirment is to use single ssh connection to the parent server and run the ping command parallely across the child servers.

Any suggestions to get around this problem will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your script slightly like instead of using the xargs command, you can use a loop to iterate over the child server IPs and execute the ping command in the background. Here's an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read child server IPs from child.csv
while IFS= read -r child_ip; do
  # Execute ping command in the background
  ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes parent "ping -c4 $child_ip" &
done < child.csv

# Wait for all background processes to finish
wait
```