# pexpect execute multiple commands in parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, pexpect

I have a number of child servers which are pingable from the parent server. The parent server is accessible from another automation server.

The requirement is to execute ping test parallelly across around 100 child servers from the parent server with a script running on the automation server.

The parent server is part of a NETAPP cluster so does not allow running any script / custom command on its terminal, so the logic needs to be controlled from the automation server itself.

I have written a script using pexpect which generates the output but does not process parallely. For 3 vms listed here, the ping test took almost 30 seconds which is more of a sequential execution. Below is the script used...

```
import pexpect, threading, time

thread_list=[]
cmd_list=['vm1','vm2','vm3']
def runping(child,cmd):
    th_name=threading.current_thread().name
    print('Running thread : '+th_name)
    cmd='ping -c10 '+cmd
    child.sendline(cmd)
    child.expect('.*>')
    print('Finished Running thread : '+threading.current_thread().name)

try:
    handle=open('results.ping.txt','wb')
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@server1', logfile=handle)
    child.expect('Password:')
    child.sendline('xxxxxxxx')
    child.expect('.*>')
    for cmds in cmd_list:
        t=threading.Thread(target=runping, args=(child,cmds))
        thread_list.append(t)

    print ('Start : '+str(time.ctime()))
    for thr in thread_list:
        thr.start()
    
    for thr in thread_list:
        thr.join()
    print ('End :'+str(time.ctime()))

    child.sendline('exit')
except:
    print('Exception')
    child.sendline('exit')
```

The requirment is to use single ssh connection to the parent server and run the ping command parallely across the child servers. I tried using multithreading as well but not working parallely.

To be more specific, it blocks in the code : child.expect('.*>') within the runping function

Any suggestions to get around this problem will be very helpful

Comment: pexpect is just simulating human's input. how can you run 3 ping in parallel manually? in the shell it's usually like `ping host &`.

Comment: I was using threading as mentioned in the code. The threads do run in blocking mode making it sequential instead of parallel. I basically need to achieve parallelism using single ssh connection

Comment: threading does not change how pexpect works. if you cannot run 3 ping in parallel manully then pexpect cannot either.

Comment: Similar question was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76407861/5976130. Did that help you in any way?

Comment: No. My case is a different one as I can not run background commands on a Netapp cluster. Also, I cannot have multiple open ssh connections due to limitations.